# How can I know if a parameter that has the type interface is actually a struct?

Tags: go, struct

I have this function that accepts an interface{}

```
func MyFunk(itf interface{}) {
}
```

And I would like to know if the itf passed is a struct, is that possible? I've tried several combinations of reflect, and the closes that I could get was `ptr` (pointer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following to detect if the argument is a struct:

```
func MyFunk(itf interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(itf)
    if v.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        // it's a struct
    }
}
```

If you also want to check for pointers to structs, then use this code:

```
func MyFunk(itf interface{}) {
    v := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(itf))
    if v.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        // it's a struct
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect) package, you can check for both struct types and pointers to structs:

```
func MyFunk(itf interface{}) {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(itf)

    if t.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
        // itf is a struct
    } else if t.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        pt := t.Elem()
        if pt.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
            // itf is a pointer to a struct
        } else {
            // itf is a pointer to something else
        }
    } else {
        // itf is something else entirely
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be [Type assertions](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) can help you

```
func MyFunk(itf interface{}) {
    s, ok := itf.(MyStruct)
    fmt.Println(s, ok)
}
```